# Dart(/Flutter): Create function in initializer list

Tags: constructor, dart, flutter, initializer-list, function-object

I am implementing a class with multiple constructors, which is internally build around a IndexedWidgetBuilder (a function object)

```
typedef IndexedWidgetBuilder = Widget Function(BuildContext context, int index);
```

Now, one of the constructors, call it `MyWidget.list` shall receive a list `myList` and create the IndexedWidgetBuilder `myBuilder` from it:

```
IndexedWidgetBuilder myBuilder
  = (BuildContext context, int index) => list[index % list.length];
```

While this code snippet alone works perfectly, I am not able to use this inside the initializer list of the constructor. A minimal working example reads

```
class MyApp {
  // Default constructor goes here

  MyApp.list(List<int> myList) :
    myBuilder = (BuildContext context, int index) => list[index % list.length];

  final IndexedWidgetBuilder myBuilder;
}
```

In Android studio, this snippet produces the error:

> The initializer type 'Type' can't be assigned to the field type '(BuildContext, int) → Widget'.

I did not find anything related on google and the language documentation also did not provide useful information. Removing the `final` keyword and moving everything into the code block of the constructor would be a solution, albeit one I would only consider a last resort.

---

Note: This is not directly a flutter problem, since it occurs with every function objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enclosing the function in parentheses seems to make the warning go away; though changes it to saying the parentheses are redundant!

```
  MyApp.list(List<Widget> list)
      : myBuilder =
            ((_, int index) => list[index % list.length]);
```

Notice how the context is unused. That means that your pre-built widgets do not have access to it, which means they can't use it for any of the `.of()` derived uses.